# how to insert foreign key data through Django Model form

Tags: django, foreign-keys

How to insert foreign key data through form. Please help . what am I doing wrong. So I have two models as follows :

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    """Model representing a book genre."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter a book genre (e.g. Science Fiction)')

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.name

    ass UserItem(models.Model):
        name= models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True)
        genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

`Forms.py` : I want to create form to store Item data. Not able to reference Genre and enter value through form.

```
    class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
        name = forms.CharField()
        genre = forms.CharField()

        class Meta:
            model = UserItem
            fields = ['name', 'genre' ]
```

`Views.py`

```
    def item(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            genre_obj = Genre.objects.get(name=request.POST.get('name'))
            print("Inside post")
            item_form = ItemForm(request.POST)
            if item_form.is_valid():
                print("valid form")
                item_form_obj = ItemForm.save(commit=False)
                item_form_obj.genre = genre_obj
                item_form_obj.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('file_upload') )
            else:
                print("invalid form")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('file_list') )
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting the `name` and `genre` fields?

Comment: I want to capture the Genre Object from Genre model and insert it into the Item form. I am not sure If I am overwriting Name also. Could you point out where I might have made the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`genre_obj` is a queryset you can not assign queryset to foreignkey field. You can assign objects which is inside the queryset so try this way

```
item_form_obj.genre = genre_obj[0]
```

and instead of using `HttpResponseRedirect` use `redirect` in both places

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect(reverse('file_upload'))
```

Comment: I changed my view like and got the error  ValueError at /projapp/item/
The view projapp.views.item didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: def item(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        genre_obj = Genre.objects.get(name=request.POST.get('name'))
        print("Inside post")
        item_form = ItemForm(request.POST)
        if item_form.is_valid():
            print("valid form")
            item_form_obj = ItemForm.save(commit=False)
            item_form_obj.genre = genre_obj[1]
            item_form_obj.save()
            return redirect(reverse('file_upload'))

Comment: GET 

Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/projapp/item/ 

Django Version:
2.2.5 

Exception Type:
ValueError 

Exception Value:
The view projapp.views.item didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
 

Exception Location:
C:\Softwares\Python\Python 3.7.4\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 126

Comment: path('item/', views.item, name='item'),

Comment: change `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('file_list') )` to `return redirect(reverse('file_list') )` also

Comment: def file_list(request):
    newfiles = Document.objects.latest()
    return render(request, 'file_list.html', {'newfiles': newfiles})


def file_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('file_list')

        else:
            form = DocumentForm()
        return render(request, 'file_upload.html',{ 'form': form }

Comment: have registered `file_list` and `file_upload` in `urls.py`?

Comment: in `def file_upload` you used `return redirect('file_list')` which should be `return redirect(reverse('file_list'))`

Comment: let me try this